# Is Visual Studio 2013 Community actually free?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I asked this question on the [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f321996-9923-4270-8bfc-e3f0faee6122/is-visual-studio-community-actually-free?forum=vssetup), but I suspect I'll get a quicker answer here.

I'm a developer working alone.  When I discovered VS Community, the website makes it look free for 1-5 developers.  When I downloaded it, installed it, and then opened it, I got a message box pop-up that said my trial had expired.

I've previously used the VS Professional trial, and uninstalled that when I got the same pop-up, so I assume there's some remnant, either on my machine, or on Microsoft's VS servers that's causing this error.

If VS Community is in fact free, there must be some way to get around this error, right?  If it isn't free and I've misunderstood, then, well, I guess that's the way it is, and I'm stuck with VS 2013 Web Express.

#### EDIT

According to Ramhound's comment, VS Community is free.

So now my question is, how do I get around this issue with VS Community checking to see if I've expended my 90-day trial of VS Professional?

Comment: Yes; Its free..

Comment: Any ideas on how to get around my issue, then?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/dn877550 and https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13350

Comment: @STTR I read those links.  Neither answered my question regarding running the software.

Comment: You need to sign in with a Microsoft account (within VS) at least once a year to renew your license.  Have you done that yet?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes, I was already signed in when I opened it the first time.

Comment: See this SO question: [VisualStudio Community 2013 prompts to update trial license](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939437/visualstudio-community-2013-prompts-to-update-trial-license)

Comment: I'll reinstall VS Community (uninstalled it in order to install Web Express) and see if logging in again makes a difference.

Comment: It is not free like Gnu, Linux, Mono Develop etc. but it may be free of charge. So while you don't have to pay to get/use it, there are many restrictions on what you can do with it.

Comment: Turns out what I needed to do was sign out and back in.

Comment: @richard - actually it more or less is.  The license is used so you can publish applications to the Windows Store

Comment: @Ramhound are you telling be that I can: use it any way I like, copy it, distribute it (for any price), modify it and study how it works?

Comment: @Richard - Its not open source.  Does not change the fact its free.  Even those projects you mention have a license that limits you in some capacity.

Comment: Are you using "free" as a contraction of "free of charge"? I am not. ( Nelson Mandela was not free of charge, but he is free. ) With respect to the 3 softwares I mentioned above, the only limitation in the licence is to stop you taking away other peoples freedom.

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me was signing out and back in.  (I also reinstalled it, but I think that wasn't necessary.)